# Understanding DNSSEC

Tags: networking, dns

So I've been trying to understand how DNS and DNSSEC works by reading the RFCs and also other various help pages around the internet, but I'm not sure if I understand completely, so i was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Here's a synopses of what I have so far:

---

DNSSEC does not actually encrypt any data, so as to keep the system efficient enough to function properly, but serves to verify the integrity and authenticity of the RRsets that a server receives.

---

The DNSKEY RR is what holds the public key that a zone can use to authenticate the signature     that comes in the RRSIG RR.

---

A zone will also have a DNSKEY in the zone apex, which can act as an entry point for the zone. There will be a DS RR on the other side of the zone cut that points to this DNSKEY.

---

I am having a bit of trouble with the NSEC RR.
It says it holds all of the resource record types associated with a RR owner name and then points to the next name.

What does owner name mean here? Does it mean the name of the zone? name of a host?

---

Another question I have has to do with packet interception. since nothings encrypted, anyone could still intercept packets, right?

If this is the case, then I'm guessing that's the point of the NSEC records, so if a resolver sees something that the NSEC says it shouldnt, it knows that packet was altered?

But I still don't exactly see how the DS and the DNSKEY in the apex come into play here, because I'm assuming thats the role they play somehow, so I have to be missing something fundamental here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: anyone know that answer or where I can look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owner name means the left-hand side name.  This is the fully-qualified domain name of the record you are talking about, in this case, an NSEC record.

Anyone can intercept the packets and see the records in them.  NSEC (or NSEC3) records are there so something exists to actually create a signature over for non-existent names.  In regular DNS, a flag in the header (NXDOMAIN) indicates that a name doesn't exist.  That can be spoofed of course.  The NSEC (or NSEC3) record basically says "no names exist between these two names, and only these RRs exist for the first name".

The DS record is just a hash of a DNSKEY.  The DNSKEY goes in the child zone and the DS record in the parent zone.  The parent then signs the DS record with the parent's zone DNSKEY.  This establishes a chain of trust between the parent and the child.